# AngularJS directive is malformed when rendered inside a div from server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-rendering

I am rendering content inside div from Database based on some conditions, data can change. Everything is working fine except When rendering a angularJs directive as content.

AngularJs directive is malformed & even its end tag is not forming as content which I rendered.

I have checked response for page from Fiddler & its is correct as I want but while rendering browser or JS is goofing up with its tag.

**At fiddler response for page request** and what I want:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gP">
   <lh-card card-url="http://api.com/User/Me/Challenge/119?format=condensed&themeId=124">
   </lh-card>
</div>
```

At browser when rendered:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gP">
   <lh-card card-url="http: api.com="" user="" me="" challenge="" 119?format="condensed&amp;themeId=124&quot;">
   </lh-card card-url="http:>
</div>
```

Due to this directive never works.

Looks `/` is removed & it broke url into parameters.

I have tried encoding Url using `httputility.urlencode` but still end-tag is misforming.
Also tried escaping `/` in url with `//`

Please help.

Comment: What's the `lhCard` directive code?

Comment: when I add directive into html with no server side code its working.  When directive is rendering from Server as content then this  issue. Directive is working fine everywhere else too.

Comment: Thanks @Michelem , seems there could be issue in directive too. Two more directive are rendering perfectly same way. Thanks for direction